# Comment appelle-t-on une personne ayant de nombreux talents variés ?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

> [Boris Vian](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Boris_vian) est un écrivain français, poète, parolier, chanteur, critique et musicien de jazz (trompettiste) [...] Il fut aussi ingénieur de l'École centrale (Promotion 42B), inventeur, scénariste, traducteur (anglo-américain), conférencier, acteur d'occasion et peintre.

Un individu parlant plusieurs langages est un polyglotte, un musicien jouant de nombreux instruments est un multi-instrumentiste. Existe-t-il un terme pour désigner ce genre de génies éclectiques ?

Comment: Ben, _génie éclectique_.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Un [polymathe](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymathie).

Comment: Polymathe est probablement le terme le plus exact, mais pas le mieux compris. En fait, jusqu'à aujourd'hui, j'ignorai qu'il existait en français (j'aurais dit qu'il s'agissait d'un anglicisme). La page wikipedia indique que seul le Littré le référence. Si être compris d'un large public est le but, 'polyvalent' ou 'humaniste' sont probablement plus adaptés.

Comment: Certes mais le large public ne connaîtra ce mot que quand on commencera à l'utiliser. :) *Humaniste* est polysémique, et peut prêter à confusion. *Polyvalent* est une horrible concaténation de grec et de latin. Je leurs préfèrerais encore la périphrase *génie éclectique*.

Comment: On en apprend tous les jours :-) Merci !

Comment: C'est peut-être la deuxième (avec le risque que ce soit la seconde) fois que je lis cette définition de  l'« **homme d'esprit universel** », et, je découvre aussi avec ravissement que *mathêma* est aussi proche de la *Connaissance* (subjective) que de la *Science* (objective) à laquelle l'Académie l'a embastillée . En espérant que parmi "ceux qui causent dans l'poste" il s'en trouve un[e] qui veuille l'employer...  Parlez-en autour de vous, c'est comme cela que vit la francophonie, et peut-être cela le remettra dans nos dictionnaires.

Comment: @cl-r: vous mettez "connaissance" et "subjectif" dans la même phrase? Très solipsistique, peut-être pas étonnant au pays de Descartes :-)

Comment: @Frank -- Me voilà donc bien *seul* avec un mot compliqué dans une mémoire de plus en plus volatile. Plus proche de la singularité de l'humain : "connaître, c'est être ; savoir, c'est avoir"... on peut arriver à se passer du second (pour retrouver l'oralité dans le présent, dans l'instant)... second (qui ne peut exister sans le premier) toujours cherchant dans le passé à expliquer le futur, ou à imaginer un futur à partir des écrits passés :-)

Answer (score 9):

On peut distinguer plusieurs cas.

On peut-être **généraliste** ou **polyvalent** (J'ai en tête le *Jack of all trades* anglais), cela veut dire que l'on est une personne qui pratique beaucoup d'activités, mais pas nécessairement spécialiste ni talentueux dans toutes ces disciplines.
**Homme-à-tout-faire**, **Touche-à-tout**, **Avoir plusieurs cordes à son arc**, **Avoir plusieurs casquettes** sont aussi des expressions que l'on peut employer.

En revanche, on peut utiliser le terme [polymathe](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymathie) comme le propose subtenante lorsque cette personne est talentueuse dans toutes les disciplines.

Comment: Quitte a avoir de l'anglais en tête, j'aime bien *versatile*.

Comment: +1 pour "touche-à-tout"

Comment: On peut utiliser l'expression "touche-à-tout de génie" pour rendre compte du côté talentueux.

Answer (score 7):

Je dirais "polyvalent"... une personne polyvalente...

Voici une définition de cet adjectif dans le TLF:

> Qui possède plusieurs aptitudes ou capacités, qui peut remplir plusieurs fonctions.

Comment: Remplir plusieurs fonctions, mais pas forcément avec talent. Une salle polyvalente sert un peu à tout mais n'est idéale pour aucune fonction.

Answer (score 4):

Pourquoi pas tout simplement «un génie» ? Ou un «humaniste» dans le sens des humanistes de la renaissance ?

Comment: J'ai toujours aussi entendu cette distinction _spécialiste_ -> une discipline / _génie_ -> toutes disciplines.

Comment: C'est en effet l'expression que tout le monde comprend, j'ai souvenir d'un **génie pluriel** décerné par un commentateur, avant d'énuméré  tous les talents d'une personnalité. Et aussi **génie aux talents multiples** . Le **génie éclectique** de substenante semble être la meilleure option. Quand à *Polymathe*, eh bien, bonjour Monsieur, très heureux de vous connaître.

Comment: Ou un **dilettante de génie** ? Malgré la connotation de médiocrité allant couramment avec *dilettante*, l'expression dans son ensemble reste, me semble-t-il, très positive.

Comment: Je n'aime pas le mot "génie" - il ne veut pas dire grand-chose a mon avis. Mais ce n'est que moi.

Answer (score 3):

Il y a aussi *touche-à-tout*, mais ça n'implique sans doute pas assez que la personne est réellement compétente dans ses multiples entreprises.

Je pense aussi à *savant multi-disciplinaire* mais c'est un peu alambiqué.

Simplement *savant* suffirait peut-être, ou alors, *érudit*.

Answer (score 2):

D'une personne qui a de multiples talents, on dira  «qu'elle a plus d'une corde à son arc».

Answer (score 1):

J'aurais dit aussi polymathe ("mathêma": la connaissance), mais c'est un terme qu'on ne voit pas très souvent, et qu'on entend encore moins souvent, il n'est pas très répandu.

Dans la presse, en général, on parlera d'un "touche-à-tout de génie", d'une personne qui a "plusieurs casquettes", qui ne "manque pas de cordes à son arc", ou même avec humour d'un "homme-orchestre" voire d'un érudit.

Au temps des humanités, on appelait simplement ça un honnête homme.

Answer (score 0):

On les appelle aussi : *hommes-orchestre*.